# Unit test static method with dependency

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I have not much experience in unit testing, especially with Mockito and now I have encountered the following situation.

```
class A {

    void setField(String obj) {
    }

    Object execute() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Meh!");
    }

}
```

---

```
class B {
    //function to be tested
    static Object someMethod() {

        A a = new A();
        a.setField("test");
        Object response = a.execute();
        //logic here

        return response;
    }
}
```

---

```
class BTest() {

   A aInstance = mock(A.class);

   @Test
   public void test_someMethod_when_exec_returns_X() {
      when(aInstance.execute()).thenReturns("X");// doesn’t work
      assertTrue("X", B.someMethod());
   }
}
```

I want to test the someMethod static method when a.execute() returns specific value. 
I know, I can create a mock object of A and pass it to someMethod function, which is not a good solution as I should change the signature of someMethod.

What is the correct solution in this case?

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible with Mockito. If you are creating a new object in that method, which you do not have access to, it cannot be mocked.

Comment: Ok, then what is the common approach in such cases. How someMethod should be tested?

Comment: Use PowerMockito and mock the constructor of A. you can find more details here https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @David_O it does, please see my answer below

Comment: @David_O How does mocking a ctor and returning whatever you want not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, the PowerMockito doesn't work in android, you can just mock android object with that. And here comes engineering solution :)

Factory class to create object A.

```
public class AFactory {

  static private AFactory sInsntance = new AFactory(); 

  public static AFactory createObject() {
      return sInsntance.createInternally();
  }

  protected TMMethodBuilder createInternally() {
     return new A();
  }

  //This function is only for testing, in order to inject factory
  @Deprecated
  public static void setFactory(AFactory mock) {
      sInsntance = mock;
  }
}
```

And create object A:

```
A a = AFactory.createObject();
```

In Test project extend AFactory and override createInternally() method to return mocked object.

```
public class AFactoryTest extends AFactory {

  private static A a = mock(A.class);

  @Override
  protected TMMethodBuilder createInternally()  {
      return a;
  } 
}
```

So in test class just do the following:

```
    factory = new AFactoryTest();
    a = factory.createInternally();
    AFactory.setFactory(factory);
    //
    when(..).thenReturn();
```

Comment: Can you give an example where you can't use PowerMock with andoird classes?

Comment: So, please create android app with it's test project. Integrate powermockito with other jars and try to build the project. Let me know if you will have success. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you check out [PowerMockito's documentation](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) you'll realize that the following is what you need:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

// execute the test with the appropriate runner
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

// prepare B for instrumentation so we can hack stuff inside
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void bShouldCallA() throws Exception {
        // create a mock for A and configure its behaviour
        A aMock = mock(A.class);
        when(aMock.execute()).thenReturn("X");

        // make sure that when A's constructor is called in the static method, the mock above is returned
        whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(aMock);

        // do the actual invocation
        Object actualResult = B.someMethod();

        // check result and interactions
        assertEquals("X", actualResult);
        verify(aMock).setField("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using only Mockito, therefore I can not test this code. So, powermockito links someMethod to aMock mock object with A a = new A(); initialization?

Comment: Mockito has its limitations as it's specified on the project page, https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ. PowerMockito extends it striving to overcome most of them. In the example above, whenever an instance of `A` is created in `B`, it will return the mock you had just configured.

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately I didn't aware of such limitations. I am implementing via factory class. will past the code when will complete.

Comment: You should try and keep questions clean and separate. Thus, if your updated scenario no longer matches this question you should open a new one

Comment: where did you see two separate questions?

Comment: @David_O You're probably overlooking something, but unless you provide the code we're unable to tell what

Comment: PowerMockito relies heavily on runtime byte code manipulation, so it won't work on Dalvik

Comment: Unless you plan on running them under dalvik, hhis shouldn't matter since you'll execute the JUnit tests on your PC or build server under a regular JVM.